# Worksheet CodeName not assigned

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to assign the code name of a worksheet to a vriable.
Some times it gets the code name correctly, and sometimes it doesn't, the variable stays null.

```
 Dim sCodeName As String
 sCodeName = Worksheets(atar).CodeName
```

`atar` is a variable that contains the worksheet name.
When i stop the code running, and coninue in debug mode, it works fine.
What can be the reason?

Comment: Maybe you're after the `CodeName` of a `Worksheet` (not a `Module`). In this case `atar` must contain a valid worksheet name (e.g.: `atar = "someSheetName"`)

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. 'atar' is a name of a worksheet.

Comment: then check `atar` to contain a _valid_ sheet name

Comment: It is a valid sheet name, some times it does work with the same value..

Comment: you may have an issue with the `ActiveWorkbook`: see @SMeaden answer

Comment: @Tzvibe if this worksheet is where your code lies, then use `ThisWorkbook` instead

Answer (score 0):

`Worksheets` without qualification refers to same as `ActiveWorkbook`, perhaps you're assuming too much about which workbook is active in some instances.

It is recommended to fully qualify Worksheets.  So get a reference to a `Workbook` object , say `wbFoo` and then use `sCodeName = wbFoo.Worksheets(atar).CodeName`

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the code below to verify that `atar` does exist in one of the worksheet names in `ThisWorkbook`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetWorksheetCodeName()

Dim sCodeName As String
Dim atar As String
Dim Sht As Worksheet

'atar = "Sheet3" '<-- for tests only

' loop through all worksheets in ThisWorkbook
For Each Sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Sht.Name Like atar Then
        sCodeName = Worksheets(atar).CodeName
        Exit For
    End If
Next Sht

End Sub
```

Comment: Tnx, I read it, I used your code to find the sheet. It finds the sheet, atar and Sht.Name are equal, and still, Worksheets(atar).CodeNamev gives a null value.

Answer (score -1):

CREATE MULTIPLE WORKSHEET BUT **SOMETIMES** NOT WORK WITH MACRO FROM WORKSHEET **ONLY WORK WITH VBA CODE RUN**

```
 Sub WSCreate()
    Dim WSA As String
    Dim WSB As String
    Dim WS As Worksheet

        WSA = "SheetA"
        WSB = "SheetB"

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        On Error Resume Next

'DELETE MULTIPLE WORKSHEETS  (IF Already Exist)
    Set WS = Nothing
    Set WS = Sheets(WSA)
        WS.Delete
    Set WS = Nothing
    Set WS = Sheets(WSB)
        WS.Delete
    Set WS = Nothing


'CREATE MULTIPLE WORKSHEETS    
   With Application.ThisWorkbook
        .Worksheets.Add.Name = WSA  'WSA = SheetA
        .VBProject.VBComponents(Worksheets(WSA).CodeName).Name = WSA
        .Worksheets.Add.Name = WSB  'WSB = SheetB
        .VBProject.VBComponents(Worksheets(WSB).CodeName).Name = WSB
    End With
     If Err <> 0 Then Exit Sub
    End Sub
```